# how to solve the Number format exception?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<form action="add">
Enter 1st number:<input type="text" name="num1"><br>
Enter 2st number:<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**AddServlet.java**

this is the servlet code.

```
package com.adithya;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet
{  
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException
    
    {
        
    int i=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
    int j=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));
    int k=i+j;
    
    
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    
    out.println("result is"+k);
    
    }

}
```

i am trying to get the result but it showing the exceptions as shown below. I can't understand the exceptions .

** EXCEPTION**

this shows exceptions like this. i am not able to identify the problem.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string
    java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:630)
    java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    com.adithya.AddServlet.service(AddServlet.java:19)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

- I can't undersand what is the mistake . i m trying to solve this from 2days .Kindly please any one help me to solve this. but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 identical names `num1`, and you are trying to call `num2` that is absent.

```
Enter 2st number:<input type="text" name="num1"><br>
```

on the:

```
Enter 2st number:<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
```

Comment: But note that the OP will also get a `NumberFormatException` if the user enters a non-number in the web form.  The code ought to *handle* the exception ... appropriately ... in the case that the user enters bad numbers.